# Trying to install a mail server on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: email, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, squirrelmail

I have installed a mail server using  `sudo tasksel install mail-server` (only two questions about proxy configuration were asked during installation), then I have installed `squirrelmail` using `apt-get install squirrelmail`. Then I have tried to access `squirrelmail` using `my_vps_ip/squirrelmail` but I get a 404, any idea? Im on Ubuntu 12.04

Note: I know there are [many risks](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155318/how-do-i-set-up-a-mail-server-on-a-linode-vps) when installing a mail server, but I need to create an email like `info@mydomain.com` in my next project.

Comment: [try this](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/how-to-run-your-own-e-mail-server-with-your-own-domain-part-1/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming. It would be a better fit for http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

ln -s /usr/share/squirrelmail/ /var/www/mail

You will be able to visit mail in 'http://domain.com/mail'

## edit

The same 'defect' has phpmyadmin :)

Comment: Are you sure that you wrote 

ln -s /usr/share/squirrelmail/ /var/www/squrrel ?

Answer (score 0):

You will need additional packages in addition to squirrelmail; go to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAQqxZVaur0 for a full installation in Ubuntu!